# Compact timer declaration

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a desktop WPF application that at some point needs to do something on a timely basis. Suppose I use DispatcherTimer class. There's a "long" way:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    // dozens lines of code

    timer1.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
}

// hundreds lines of code later

DispatcherTimer timer1 = new DispatcherTimer();

void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff
}

void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.IsEnabled = checkBox1.IsChecked.Value;
}
```

It works ok, but I don't like that timer-related code is separated in two parts. I could re-create timer each time I start it:

```
DispatcherTimer timer1;

void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff
}

void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1 = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer1.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
    timer1.IsEnabled = checkBox1.IsChecked.Value;
}
```

but that feels wrong.
Also DispatcherTimer have constructor that take EventHandler as an argument that I may use kinda like that:

```
DispatcherTimer timer1 = new DispatcherTimer(
    new TimeSpan(0,0,1),
    DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle,
    new EventHandler(timer1_Tick),
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);

void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff
}

void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.IsEnabled = checkBox1.IsChecked.Value;
}
```

I like it, it's simple and compact, but you can't create EventHandler this way, the compiler says "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or blah-blah-blah".

Is there a way to make this nice code actually work?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with just doing it all in the constructor? That's how I normally do it:

```
private DispatcherTimer _timer1;

public MainWindow()
{
    // dozens lines of code
    _timer1 = new DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 
                                  DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle,
                                  timer1_Tick,
                                  Dispatcher);
}
```

Comment: `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` should just be `Dispatcher` i.e. the Dispatcher of the Window. Using CurrentDispatcher is generally dangerous, because it creates a new Dispatcher in case the current thread does not have one assigned. You don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind changing field to property (with backing field), you can do initialization in getter (only on first read):

```
DispatcherTimer _timer1;
DispatcherTimer timer1
{
    get
    {
        return _timer1 ??= new DispatcherTimer
        (
            new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1),
            DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle,
            new EventHandler(timer1_Tick),
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher
        );
    }
}

void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just create the timer in the constructor instead. Optionally with a local function or lambda for the handler to keep it close to the initialization.

If you follow the [stylecop code style rules](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1201.md) the code should be ordered as

- Fields
- Constructors
- ...
- methods

So if there are hundreds of lines of code between the declaration and initialization of your timer there might be other design issues you need to address first.

If you have multiple constructors you should have one constructor that is guaranteed to run, and that all the other delegates some of the construction to.